# How do I set permission for Mathematica to import other files on my machine?

Tags: import

Sorry that this is a very stupid question, but when I first loaded the new version of Mathematica (13.0.1.0) it asked me to "Allow Mathematica to open files" and I accidentally clicked "Deny".  How do I fix that?

The symptom is:  I cannot do an Import of a .gif or .ods file if it is in a subdirectory of my main /Users/[name] directory, but I can successfully do so if it is in /Users/[name].

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you please elaborate on the current symptoms as well? Are you able to open *.nb files?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what "Allow Mathematica to open files" does my guess would be it affects the settings under Edit->Preferences->Security->Notebook Security.

Comment: I have added more detail.  Thank you for responding.